# Python 3 iterate json return object

Tags: python, json, api, iteration, xml-rpc

I have a JSON return object that I need the value from the 'id' field number for each row return.

output variable (json return object):

```
[{'public_key': '21A8CAEEDC0B5A0A88657C796089D9CF83BC057B', 'flags': 256, 'algorithm': 8, 'digest': 'C0B0483159C3C2B0616BC27AC12D251BF30DFBF5E2B2A6D2DE964A3BAAC68564', 'id': 28105, 'digest_type': 2, 'keytag': 57881, 'date_created': <DateTime '20150620T01:49:46' at 805f34518>}, {'public_key': '406F0435E626AD582D4A403A9AB5E52F86CC3D15', 'flags': 256, 'algorithm': 8, 'digest': 'D06634258CCD3DD7BA8F7796828A6B4DFE142F01C964D851B9FAFE3D9CC7C712', 'id': 28141, 'digest_type': 2, 'keytag': 60608, 'date_created': <DateTime '20150621T01:44:55' at 805f34630>}]
```

I have the JSON libraries loaded but python does not like my formatting

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makecustdomain.py", line 262, in <module>
    json_object = json.load(output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

code:

```
    domain = 'domain2.com'
    api = client.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
    apikey = 'privateKey'
    output = api.domain.dnssec.list(apikey, domain)
    json_object = json.load(output)
    for id in json_object[7]:
            print(id)
```

expected output:

```
28105
28141
```

How do I return the value for 'id' from my JSON return object?

Comment: What is your expected output? `id`'s of all documents in the son array?

Comment: @n9code each row in the JSON object is a DNS delegation signing record. If 'any' pop up, I need to delete them all based on id number. so I need all the id numbers in a list or some other iteratable format, so I can delete them right away. . i.e. [45672, 56234 ...]  ->  api.domain.dnssec.delete(apikey, id)

Comment: [James Mills' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30960160/3264192) gets you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* `output` will always be a `list` (*because you're using RPC here and RPC generally serializes results into native types*) and so you'll have to do something like this:

```
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter

output = api.domain.dnssec.list(apikey, domain)
ids = map(itemgetter("id"), output)
pprint(ids)
```

**Update:** If the list of ids come back as `["123 456", "789"]` you and you want a flattened list of ids you *could* do something like:

```
ids = list(chain(*map(str.split, map(itemgetter("id"), output))))
```

Comment: It certainly prints out the whole JSON object, which I was able to do before. But still no closer to the 'id' value  http://paste.ee/p/TNEKW

Comment: Then you'll have to *clarify* your question and show us what ``output`` looks like.

Comment: 'output' published in the original question my friend. The JSON object is there. output = JSON object.

Comment: This answer is *correct* for what you've shown us. If the list you described above in representative of what ``output`` comes back as; the ``json.read()`` is superfluous and mapping the function ``itemgetter("id")`` to this list of dicts will yield a list of ids.

Comment: no brother, the id field has ''28105 and 28141" in them.  I will edit the question to state the same.  I was counting on "I need the values of the id field" to be clear enough. I apologize.

Comment: If the values is to be assumed as "space separated" that wasn't obvious; no :)

Comment: do you know how to get to it?